# Can I stop headnotes in one chapter of my thesis or edit it?

Tags: sectioning, header-footer

I am using my university thesis style and my main file code is shown below:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{ecsthesis}


\begin{document}
\frontmatter 
\title      {}
\authors    {}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\newpage
\chapter*{Abbreviation}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abbreviation}
\input{Abbreviation}
\newpage
\chapter*{Nomenclature}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Nomenclature}
\input{Nomenclature}
\newpage
\authorshipdeclaration{}
\newpage
\acknowledgements{Thanks to no one.}
\mainmatter
\include{Introduction}
\appendix
\include{AppendixI}
\include{AppendixII}
\backmatter
\bibliography{references}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\end{document}
```

My problem is: The headnote of Abbreviation and Nomenclature chapters are 'list of tables' !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

How can I fix this problem please ?

Comment: template broken, reach to the author.

Comment: Please make your code compilable without included files we do not have.

Comment: `markboth{List of Abbrevs}{List of Abbrevs}` as discussed so many times on this site.